# How to create a [python,web2py,postgresql] stack

Tags: postgresql, web2py

I am wondering if it's possible to create a portable stack which contains web2py (and of course python) and postgresql. The goal is to have a web application which can be installed and runs on any server under any platform(*nix,windows).
Which approach can help me to do this ?
Thanks.

Comment: more details would be useful, so far the only thing would prevent portability would be postgresql, since it has to run on the server, so you, so, for this you might need a potable DB, that's what sqlite does, the rest already comes out of the box with web2py, if you work with the source version should work on any OS.

Comment: thanks deadPoet. Is there a way that web2py work with postgresql like the bitnami django stack ?

Comment: didn't know about bitnami, but reading the bitnami django docs, basically all you need to do is replace the database engine string in db.py, web2py comes all along with most of that stuff and some more, i.e, in a single instance of web2py you can run different apps and each with a different database engine or in the same, I guess even the same database with independent prefix for each app.

Comment: I think that Docker [link](https://www.docker.com/whatisdocker/) will be perfect for me, thanks deadPoet.